# sequelize not recognizing table name

Tags: sequelize.js, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

My requirement is not to define/alter table definition from Sequelize. So, I haven't called `await sequelize.sync();`

However, the problem is that Sequelize does not recognize the tables and instead fires the query with double quotes. I copied the same query from the console to pgadmin and it's not working with double quotes, but when they're removed, it works. I'm not sure if we need to make any configuratin changes.

```
SELECT "id" AS "userId", "name" FROM "schema.table_name" AS "tableAlias" WHERE "tableAlias"."name"
```

Exception:

```
[Nest] 22364  - 03/21/2022, 6:22:21 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] relation "schema.table_name" does not exist
```

Model Definiation:

```
@Table({
  timestamps: false,
  freezeTableName: true,
  tableName: "schema.table_name"
})

    export class TableAlias  extends Model<TableAlias>{
    
      @PrimaryKey
      @Column({
       field: 'id'
        })
       userId: number;
    
      
       @Column({field: 'name'})
        name: number;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't indicate table name along with the schema. Please indicate it separately in `schema` option:

```js
@Table({
  timestamps: false,
  freezeTableName: true,
  tableName: "table_name",
  schema: "schema"
})

    export class TableAlias  extends Model<TableAlias>{
    
      @PrimaryKey
      @Column({
       field: 'id'
        })
       userId: number;
    
      
       @Column({field: 'name'})
        name: number;
    }
```